# Make cell-contents uppercase on value change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not experienced in VBA and I've pieced together a small script to make the contents of a cell uppercase once any value has been entered. The script should apply this only to a certain range of cells, in my case J11:AK25.

The script works (it makes the contents of a cell uppercase once something is entered or changed), but Excel crashes right after entering or changing a value. This happens in Excel 2013.

The code I have right now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J11:AK24")) Is Nothing Then RunUp
End Sub


Sub RunUp()
 Range("J11:AK25") = [index(upper(J11:AK25),)]
End Sub
```

Anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn off the events before calling the other sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Goto SafeOut
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J11:AK24")) Is Nothing Then RunUp

SafeOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That being said, this may be safer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo SafeOut
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J11:AK24"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In rng
            cel.Value = UCase$(cel.Value)
        Next cel
    End If

SafeOut:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I used your second suggestion and it works like a charm! Thank you very much!!